# Android path to resource inside package

Tags: android, resources, path, media-player

I tried to add a video path to an Android sample project - MediaPlayerDemo

I can playback the video when it stored in sdcard, the path is 
"file:///sdcard/dcim/a.m4v"

But I can't playback the video when it stored in res/drawable. the path is
"android.resource://" +this.getPackageName () + "/" + R.drawable.a

I can read the id of the video in debug mode, but just can't replay the video.

How to solve it?

**UPDATES**

Thank you for the reply, so far i have tried:

1. put the video in assets, set path to "file:///android_asset/a.m4v".
2. put the video in raw, set path to 
   ("android.resource://" +this.getPackageName () + "/" + R.raw.a) or ("android.resource://" +this.getPackageName () + "/raw/a)

but none of them can playback video.
My video is 1.8Mb, does it matter?

Comment: use this way 'Uri myUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.drawable.a);
videoHolder.setVideoURI(myUri);'

Comment: but right way to put your video in assets or raw folder as Mayani ans.

Comment: I tried many methods but still get a 
setDataSourceFD failed: status=0x80000000

Comment: ok then post your code and log?

Answer (score 7):

Create a new folder with name **raw** in **res** folder, if already created let it be. Copy your playable video file (e.g., **myvideo.mp4**) to **raw** folder. Use below code in your app.

```
String uriPath = "android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/raw/myvideo";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriPath);
mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
```

I tested, its working for me. If the video is playable from sdcard then only it will play from raw folder, otherwise it will show a dialog box says **Cannot play video**.

try it and let me know what happened.

Comment: I tried your method, still doesn't work. Using API level10.
I can't even play video from sdcard by VideoView.  I am using MediaPlayer.
Thanks anyway!

Comment: i was able at last to playback my local video! Thks but don't forget to remove file extension in your uri path, don't know why but it was not working until i removed .mp4 extension

Answer (score 2):

FYI, drawable is to store icons, images, drawables for the application. So You can put the same video either in `assets` or in `raw` folder.

Comment: thanks. but I still can't playback video in these two folder.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, but not a straight forward way.

First, the file not found problem is not the path problem, it is because the permission problem.

To solve that, many people suggest copy the file into FileInputStream.  But still got file not found problem.

But the File can be written to Inputstream.  However, setDataSource() of Mediaplayer class does not acccept InpuStream.  Therefore need to write the Inputstream to a temp File by BufferedOutputStream.

finally, setDataSource(tempfile_path) without error.

Comment: File tempfile = File.createTempFile("mediaplayer", "temp");
            String tempfilepath = tempfile.getAbsolutePath();
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(tempfile);
            BufferedOutputStream bis = new BufferedOutputStream(fo);
            byte buf[] = new byte[128];
            do {
             int numread = is.read(buf);
             if (numread <= 0)
              break;
             bis.write(buf, 0, numread);
            } while (true); 
            
            
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(tempfilepath);

Comment: Please use the Edit link button below your post to add more information to it instead of using the comment section. It is much harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old and still not answered well so here I will answer.

First of all, do not put videos in the assets folder. It is a bad practice. Create another folder (Preferably one named raw).

The second thing is that please do not use m4v format. Use a mp4 video.

Here is the code to insert video:

```
    //Here it is assumed here that the file name of video in raw folder is demo        
    VideoView video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    video.setVideoPath("android.resource//" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.demo);
    video.start();
```

Hope this clarifies your doubt!